# How to add a div that does not damage the view?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

My case is like this

My view is like this :

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <ul class="list-inline list-photo">
            @foreach($product->photos as $i => $photo)
            <li id="thumbnail-view-{{$i}}" >
                  ...
            </li>
            @endforeach

            @for($i = count($product->photos); $i < 5; $i++) 
                <li id="thumbnail-upload-li-{{$i}}">
                    <a href="javascript:" class="thumbnail thumbnail-upload" id="thumbnail-view-{{$i}}">
                        <span class="fa fa-plus fa-2x"></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                ...
            @endfor
            </div>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to add div before @for like this :

```
<div id="test">
    @for($i = count($product->photos); $i < 5; $i++) 
        <li id="thumbnail-upload-li-{{$i}}">
            ...
        </li>
        ...
    @endfor
</div>
```

When I add div, the view becomes not tidy

I need to add div. So I want to call it from javascript

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: You have errors in your HTML. `<div>` cannot be a child of `<ul>`. You also have an extra closing `</div>` tag. (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul)

Answer (score 0):

try to use span because div has a line break compare to span or another option is to use css to suite your needs

Comment: No, `<span>` and `<div>` cannot be children of `<ul>`.

Comment: yeah right man thanks i forgot that . css i think will do the trick

Answer (score 0):

The reason your view "becomes not tidy", as you put it, is because you are producing invalid HTML. The only valid child of `<ul>` is an `<li>` element. You therefore have two choices, either use multiple lists and add a class/ID to each one, like this:

```
<ul class="list-inline list-photo thumbnail-view">
    @foreach($product->photos as $i => $photo)
    <li id="thumbnail-view-{{$i}}" >
            ...
    </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
<ul class="list-inline list-photo thumbnail-upload">
    @for($i = count($product->photos); $i < 5; $i++) 
        <li id="thumbnail-upload-li-{{$i}}">
            <a href="javascript:" class="thumbnail thumbnail-upload" id="thumbnail-view-{{$i}}">
                <span class="fa fa-plus fa-2x"></span>
            </a>
        </li>
        ...
    @endfor
</ul>
```

Or you can apply a class to specific row(s) you want to select with JavaScript or CSS if you want to style them differently:

```
<ul class="list-inline list-photo">
    @foreach($product->photos as $i => $photo)
    <li id="thumbnail-view-{{$i}}" class="thumbnail-view">
            ...
    </li>
    @endforeach

    @for($i = count($product->photos); $i < 5; $i++) 
        <li id="thumbnail-upload-li-{{$i}}" class="thumbnail-upload">
            <a href="javascript:" class="thumbnail thumbnail-upload" id="thumbnail-view-{{$i}}">
                <span class="fa fa-plus fa-2x"></span>
            </a>
        </li>
        ...
    @endfor
</ul>
```

Comment: How is that relevant to this question?